# In Internet Explorer not able to convert UTC date to local date

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer-11, momentjs, datejs

Here is date that I received from Backend `"2017-05-23T18:30:00"`,

This works fine in Chrome:

- Call:  `new Date('2017-05-23T18:30:00').toString()`
- Result: `"Wed May 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"`

But on the Internet Explorer:

- Call: `new Date('2017-05-23T18:30:00').toString()`
- Result: `"Tue May 23 2017 18:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"`,

What to do get local date time from UTC date in Internet Explorer as I am getting in Chrome?

Comment: Does it help if you specifically mark the time as UTC: `2017-05-23T18:30:00Z`

Comment: @Henry Thanks, its work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) to parse your input cross browser. Then you can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to display your moment object. If you need to convert moment object to JavaScript date you can use [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) method.

Use [`local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) if you want to convert your moment to local time.

See [Local vs UTC vs Offset](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/) for additional information.

Here a live sample:

```js
var input = '2017-05-23T18:30:00';
var m = moment.utc(input);
console.log(m.format());
console.log(m.toDate().toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE browser will take in the format of 'mm-dd-yy'. if you give in the format of 'yy-mm-dd' it results Invalid Date.

use following function to convert UTC to LocalDate.

```
function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(utcDate) {
    var formattedDate = utcDate.getMonth()+'-'+utcDate.getDate()+'-'+utcDate.getFullYear();
    var hours = utcDate.getHours();
        var minutes = utcDate.getMinutes();
        var seconds = utcDate.getSeconds()
        var newDate = new Date(formattedDate + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes+":"+seconds+" UTC");
    return newDate;   
}
var localDate = convertUTCDateToLocalDate(yourUTCDate);
```